# Want to increase width with scroll but is decreasing instead

Tags: jquery, scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/efpsj1wp/

HTML:

```
<div class="page">
<p> content</p>
<p> content</p>
<p> content</p>
<p> content</p>
<p> content</p>

<div id="waveBlue"></div>

<p> content</p>
<p> content</p>
<p> content</p>
<p> content</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#waveBlue {
  height: 43px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var $page = $('.page')
        var $waveBlue = $('#waveBlue')
        //Get height of page
        var $pageHeight = $page.outerHeight();
        //Find the percent scrolled from page set to width of waveBlue
        var scrollPercent = ($pageHeight - window.scrollY)/$pageHeight;
        if(scrollPercent>=0) {
            $waveBlue.css('width', scrollPercent*200);
        }
    });   
});
```

As you can see in my fiddle, the width of the blue div is decreasing as I scroll down the page. Instead, I'd like it to increase it but can't figure out how.

Bonus: is there any way I can increase the width of the div starting from right to left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you with your first question:

```
var scrollPercent = 1-($pageHeight - window.scrollY)/$pageHeight;
```

In order to increase the width from right to left, do this:

```
waveBlue {
 height: 43px;
 width: 0px;
 right:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 background: blue;
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to start the width-increase at a certain amount of pixels down the page?

Comment: i dont understand your question

Comment: Sorry I meant: Is there any way to start the width-decrease at a certain amount of pixels down the page?

Comment: I want the blue bar to stay at 200px until I scroll down 100px from the top of the page. At 100px down from the top of the page, I would like to trigger the width decrease.

Comment: Just by adding a [if](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) statement like `if(scrollPercent > 0.50) scrollPercent=1-scrollPercent;` you can do this or if you want to add this feature according to height scrolled add `window.scrollY` in the if statement   hope i am clear

Comment: you are welcome if you can upvote my answer so that others get benefitted. Cheers